# How to install docker client only without docker engine

Tags: docker, image, shell, docker-engine

I want to write a script which going to use docker API. It will communicate with the docker engine which runs on the host machine.
I don't wanna install the entire docker to my image just CLI and later use the host network to communicate with the docker engine.

My script under the hood gonna run commands like `docker image inspect someiamge`

Comment: There are [Docker SDKs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) for many popular languages, and using one of these might be safer and easier than trying to script `docker` subprocesses.

Comment: @DavidMaze the SDK client is not supported for PHP. Look like using SDK would add additional dependency which is poorly maintained. I don't think it would be easier.

Comment: @DavidMaze I think you should point to SDK as an answer to this question.  
one of the possible ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can use binary distribution of docker, which can be downloaded from [here](https://download.docker.com/linux/static/), you can get docker client binaries there.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/binaries/) of installation of a docker from binaries. Just skip part of starting docker engine and make sure that your docker client points to a correct remote engine (mounting /var/run/docker.sock)

Answer (score 0):

I thinking about using [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) to extract the CLI client.

```
COPY --from=docker:latest /usr/local/bin/docker  /usr/local/bin/
```

Example of dockerfile

```
FROM php:8-cli-alpine

COPY --from=docker:latest /usr/local/bin/docker  /usr/local/bin/
```

And later you could use this image with following command

```bash
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint docker -v docker run -it --rm --entrypoint docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock yourimage:tag image ls
```

This has a significant downside. The docker image does not support `linux/arm/v7` architecture.

```
 => ERROR [linux/arm/v7 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/docker:latest                                                                                                                        4.5s
 => ERROR [linux/arm/v7 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/composer:2
```

Better to use SDK.

Comment: Copying binaries between images like this doesn't necessarily work reliably.  You also need to know what shared-library dependencies and other files that binary needs, and for some basic things like the system C library there might be incompatibilities between the versions that binary needs and what's available in your destination image.

Comment: @DavidMaze as far as I can remember Go consists of one binary file which does not really on any shared library.